# An object reference is required to access non-static member when trying to use arraylist

Tags: c#

What could be the problem?
I get this message:
An object reference is required to access non-static member labb3.linkClass.getLinks()

```
    namespace labb3
{
    public partial class visalinks : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            userClass newUser = (userClass)Session["userClass"];
            ArrayList Poster = linkClass.getLinks();

            foreach (object o in Poster) {
                linkClass lnks = (linkClass)o;
                Response.Write(lnks.webbadress);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In a static context, you don't have an instance, that's why you can't access a non-static member without explicitly mentioning an object reference.

In fact, you can access a non-static member in a static context by specifying the object reference explicitly:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

linklClass is name of your class, and getLinks is a method in this class - but getLinks isn't static, so in order to use it - you have to create instance of the class:

```
linkClass inst = new linkClass();
inst.getLinks()
```

or... just make getLinks static, if it's possible.

Answer (score 3):

You're calling the `getLinks` instance method of a variable that isn't declared or initialized .. The message is pretty descriptive.