# C#error an object reference is required to access non-static member(serial communication between unity and arduino)

Tags: unity-game-engine, arduino

There was the errors "an object reference is required to access non-static member."

Do you know how to solve this problems?
I don't want to use "static" because unity gui "button- Onclick" isn't able to use the static member.

[image]

like this screenshot, if we use the static member on GUI(canvas-button-button click), that static member don't be listed("missing ------------")

my code is blow.

Sending.cs

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Threading;
public class Sending : MonoBehaviour{
    //public static SerialPort sp = new SerialPort("COM4",9600,Parity.
    public SerialPort sp = new SerialPort("----------);
    public string message2;
    float timePassed = 0.0f;
    //Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        OpenConnection();
    }

    //Update is called once per frame
    void Update(){
        //timePassed+= Time.deltaTime;
        //if(timePassed)=0.2f){
        //print("BytesToRead" +sp.BytesToRead);
        message2 = sp.ReadLine ();
        print (message2);
        ///timePassed = 0.0f;
        //}
    }

    public void OpenConnection()
    {
        if(sp != null)
        {
            if (sp.IsOpen) {
                sp.Close ();
                print ("Closing port, because it was already open!");
            }  else {
                sp.Open ();//open the connection
                sp.ReadTimeout = 16;
                print ("Port Opened!");
                //message = "Port Opened";
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            if (sp.IsOpen)
            {
                print ("Port is already open");
            }
            else
            {
                print ("Port == null");
            }
        }
    }
    void OnApplicationQuit()
    {
        sp.Close();
    }
    public void sendStop(){
        sp.Write ("s");
    }
    public void sendForward(){
        sp.Write("f");
    }
    public void sendBack(){
        sp.Write("b");
    }
    public void sendRight(){
        sp.Write("r");
    }
    public void sendLeft(){
        sp.Write("l");
    }
}
```

also, there are some script.

CallForward.cs

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class CallForward: MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    void OnMouseDown(){
        print ("Clicked");
        Sending.sendForward();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: This project is to connect unity with arduino to control DC motor by uGUI.

Comment: Like CallForward.cs, I have CallStop,Right,Left,Back.cs.

Comment: I have already controlled the dc motor from Unity object "Cube" to Arduino by Serial Communication.
However, that use static.
By using same algorism, I try coding uGUI. As a result, uGUI>Canvas>Button(Onclick missing). 
And now, I remove the static from

Sending.cs
public SerialPort sp = new SerialPort("----------);
and
public (static) void sendStop(){
        sp.Write ("s");
    }

Comment: public void sendForward,sendRight,sendLeft,sendBack are same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An object reference is required to access non-static member when trying to use arraylist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608644/an-object-reference-is-required-to-access-non-static-member-when-trying-to-use-a)

Comment: @Kardux
thanks for your reply.
I have checked that page, but I don't solved out my problem:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to get the Sending-script before you can use it. Only Static classes can be used without first initiating them.

```
GameObject.Find("GameObjectWithSendingScript").GetComponent<Sending>().sendForward();
```

Comment: thanks for you advice.
which should I attach this script,"Sending.cs" or "CallForward.cs"?

Comment: This code is for where you get the error, in CallForward.cs. Try using my code instead of `Sending.sendForward();`

Comment: @peter
Thanks,peter.for your gread advice.
I solved out this problem. You are GOD! an great Engineer!!!!!
Oh, GREAATTTT!!!!!!!I really appreciate you!

Comment: Haha, glad to help! Who's peter though?

Comment: Oh, sorry for mistaking your name, my god.Your name is Fredrik, not peter. I'm really appreciate you because you save me for debugging for a long long time, two days!!!!!!!
you're great god. THANKS:)